# java socket server - load balance

Tags: java, sockets, server, load-balancing, haproxy

A brief introduction of the business: Online meeting for multiple participants.

The implementation is:

1) Java socket servers receive images/screenshots from one client and then deliver the images/screenshots to other clients. So each client is a long connection, and will send/receive large data frequently.

2) The client side may be written in multiple language: c++, java, object-c etc.

My question is :
How should I do for load balance in the server side?

1. If I use HAProxy, I understand HAproxy can dispatch the request from client to a real java socket server machine.  But I think the input stream from client side is large, whether the HAProxy is appreciate for this?
2. If I do not use HAProxy, and write load balance program in server side(in the same machine) . How can I implement this? Zookeeper or any other component I can leverage?

Comment: Too board, you need to make some tests according to your needs. I think there dozens of programs already doing what you want to reimplement, i.e. Teamviewer, Skype, Mikogo ...

Comment: You can look to ZeroMQ and nanomsg

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. I know Teamviewer, Skype can do this. But what I want is not a software can do online meeting, I need load balance tech used for the Java socket servers.